# How can i unban people with a Discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I need some help with my Discord bot... somehow my bot doesn't work. Thanks for the help!

```js
if (command === `unban`) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("UNBAN_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("Nö, kein Bock!");

    const member = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (!member) return message.reply("Es wurde kein Member erwähnt!");

    if (!member.bannable) return;
    message.channel.send("Der User wurde entbannt!");
    message.guild.members.unban(member);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken straight from [Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=unban)

```
// Unban a user by ID (or with a user/guild member object)
guild.members.unban('84484653687267328')
```

You must make sure that the user you are referring as `member` is actually a member and that the your bot has permission to `BAN_MEMBERS`. I would recommend changing the variable name as `member` is used already.